# NodeJS Redis EXAT not setting up unix timestamp correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, memcached, ioredis

I am working on NodeJS application with ioredis. **Redis Version: 6.2.6**

I want to set redis key expiry after 4 months on specific date.

I refer lot document to set expiry time, mentioning few of the document below.

1. [Ioredis TTL exipry examples](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/807cfc0e211f72885e00228edc5e72878916a938/examples/ttl.js)
2. [redis expiryat documentation](https://redis.io/commands/expireat/)

I tried **redis.expireat("foo", 1682812800);**

It's setting up invalid timestamp like 7728764, which i got from redis.ttl("foo");

Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong here? or please help me with correct documentation which i can reffer to setup unix timestamp as ttl.

Answer (score 0):

The `ttl` command in Redis (https://redis.io/commands/ttl/) returns the number of seconds remaining until the key is considered expired.  It doesn't return the timestamp at which the key will be considered expired.  When you set an expiry with `expireat` you are providing a timestamp and `ttl` essentially returns the number of seconds left until that timestamp.  I believe Redis is behaving as expected here.  If you want to work out when the key expires as a timestamp, you could get the TTL value in seconds using `ttl` then add it to the current timestamp in your code.